# How to iterate thru an arraylist and do an action every X times using for loops? Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to iterate thru an ArrayList of strings that are made up of lines of parsed HTML. How can I use a double for loop to print 0-353, while printing an extra line every 4? Thanks for all the help

What I must do is go to each line, check to see if it is either the world, country, members, or activity. I will than add all 4 of that data into an object, every time I finish filling the object I must than start a new object to add to another array list of my objects.

```
<a id='slu-world-301' class='server-list__world-link'        href='http://oldschool.runescape.com/game?world=301'>Old School 1</a>
<td class='server-list__row-cell server-list__row-cell--country server-list__row-cell--US'>United States</td>
<td class='server-list__row-cell server-list__row-cell--type'>Free</td>
<td class='server-list__row-cell'>Trade - Free</td>
<a id='slu-world-302' class='server-list__world-link' href='http://oldschool.runescape.com/game?world=302'>Old School 2</a>
<td class='server-list__row-cell server-list__row-cell--country server-list__row-cell--GB'>United Kingdom</td>
<td class='server-list__row-cell server-list__row-cell--type'>Members</td>
<td class='server-list__row-cell'>Trade - Members</td>
<a id='slu-world-303' class='server-list__world-link' href='http://oldschool.runescape.com/game?world=303'>Old School 3</a>
<td class='server-list__row-cell server-list__row-cell--country server-list__row-cell--DE'>Germany</td>
<td class='server-list__row-cell server-list__row-cell--type'>Members</td>
<td class='server-list__row-cell'>-</td>
```

My Current code:

```
for(int i=1;i<(strs.size() / 4) + 1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        System.out.println(???? WHAT DO I PUT HERE ????)
    }
        System.out.println("-----------------");
}
```

Comment: what is `strs` in your code? and whats not working for you?

Comment: are you trying to print out every line of html or just the integers 0-353?

Comment: What about the size of your strs? It seems it is 354, hence you are getting values upto 351,since 354/4=88. To get tge desired output use i<= strs.size()/4.

Comment: Well I have in row html for members, world, country, and activity, that are all in line but every 4 I need to add it into an object, than create a new object.

Strs is my html that has been parsed, I can post the whole code if need be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend use % this Remainder operator
reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

```
0 % 4 = 0   
1 % 4 = 1   
2 % 4 = 2   
3 % 4 = 3   
4 % 4 = 0



for(int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(i);
    if (i%4 == 3) {
        System.out.println("---------");
    }
}
```

output is

```
0
1
2
3
---------
4
5
6
7
---------
8
9
10
11
---------
```

---

if code is below

```
for(int i=0;i<strs.size();i++) {
    if(i%4 ==0) {
        System.out.println("---------");
    } 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

output will be

```
 ------------ //will more one ----- because 0 % 4 = 0
 0
 1
 2
 3
 ------------
 4
 5
 6
 7
 ------------
 8
 9
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints our only 0-351 is

```
i<(strs.size() / 4)
```

since `strs.size() = 354` or `353`(from comments), your outer loop becomes

```
for(int i=0;i< 88;i++)
```

and hence you achieve max of `87*4 + 3` => `351`.

---

You can change to iterate as:

```
for(int i=0;i<strs.size();i++) {
    if(i%4 ==0) {
        System.out.println("---------");
    } 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: strs.size() only equals 353, but every 4th item has to be the end of the object, and has to allow for a new one so it can continue every 4.

Comment: @Kushroom the result for your case would still be the same, since 353/4 would also lead to `i<88`

Comment: That worked out actually after rechanging my approuch.

Comment: @Kushroom Cool (y) Glad to know I was able to help.